# CodeSlider Tab Size Adjustment

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, slider

I'm using [this](http://kevinbatdorf.github.com/codaslider/) jquery plugin. Here's my html:

```
<div class="account_window" style="display:none;">
    <div class="coda-slider"  id="slider-id">
      <div>
        <h2 class="title">Option1</h2>
        <p>Stuff for option 1</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2 class="title">Password</h2>
        <form id="change_Pass" action="" method="post">
            Current Password<span style="color:red;">*</span><input type="password" id="change_password" name="change_password"><br>
            New Password<span style="color:red;">*</span><input type="password" id="new_password" name="new_password"><br>
            Verify Password<span style="color:red;">*</span><input type="password" id="verify_password" name="verify_password"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="change_pass_submit">
         </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the jquery:

```
$('#slider-id').codaSlider({
    firstPanelToLoad: 1,
    dynamicArrows: false
});
```

So when i remove this line `style="display:none;"`, the tabs work and looks perfect. But when I add it the tabs look like this:
[image: CodaSlider]

I don't know why. There are no console errors. [Here](http://jsbin.com/welcome/37373/edit) is a working demo of the problem. Why is it displaying so oddly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you're having is because the Coda Slider creates a wrapper element around the slider when it's initialized, which does not play nicely with its parent element being hidden.

The workaround for this is to make the slider initialize *after* the `account_window` has been made visible.

To do this, change your jQuery to:

```
$('#show_coda').click(function(){
  $('.account_window').show();

  $('#slider-id').codaSlider({
    firstPanelToLoad: 1,
    dynamicArrows: false
  });
});
```

Comment: yah but this keeps appending to the previous initialization. Anyway to initialize it once

Comment: Do you mean if the button is clicked over and over again, more and more sliders show up? If you want to get rid of that just add `$('#show_coda').hide();` inside your `click` callback.